# Why does logwatch hang processing sshd on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 server?

Tags: server, 18.04, sshd, logwatch

```
$ sudo logwatch --service sshd --debug 100 --output stdout
...
TimeFilter: Period is day

TimeFilter: SearchDate is (2019-10-13T..:..:..\.[0-9]+[+-][0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} )

TimeFilter: Debug SearchDate is (2019-10-13T \ [0-9]+[+-][0-9]{2} [0-9]{2} )
DEBUG: Inside ApplyStdDate...
DEBUG: Looking For: (Oct 13 ..:..:.. )
DEBUG: Looking For: (2019-10-13T..:..:..\.[0-9]+[+-][0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} )

export LOGWATCH_LOGFILE_LIST='/var/log/auth.log /var/log/auth.log.1 '
export LOGWATCH_ARCHIVE_LIST='/var/log/auth.log.2.gz /var/log/auth.log.3.gz /var/log/auth.log.4.gz '
Processing Service: sshd
 ( cat /var/cache/logwatch/logwatch.xV7LYbVy/secure  |  /usr/bin/perl /usr/share/logwatch/scripts/shared/onlyservice 'sshd' |/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/logwatch/scripts/shared/removeheaders '' |/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/logwatch/scripts/services/sshd) 2>&1 

TimeFilter: Period is day

TimeFilter: SearchDate is ( 2019-Oct-13 ..h ..m ..s )

TimeFilter: Debug SearchDate is ( 2019-Oct-13 h m s )
```

That's it.  It's hung.  The file `/var/cache/logwatch/logwatch.xV7LYbVy/secure` has a bunch of logging info in it.

If I say `--service kernel` it completes normally in an instant.  I'm running Logwatch 7.4.3 (released 12/07/16)

Comment: Have tried it without debug mode or lowering its level  less than 3 ?

Comment: You  can try using version 7.5.2 or higher like recommended in this Q&A: https://sourceforge.net/p/logwatch/discussion/1115929/thread/766a83fd/